# What is the notation for joint probability?

Tags: probability, notation

I'm making a design and trying to write $P(A \text{ and } B) \leq P(A \cup B)$. I'm wondering if these are all correct:

- $P(A,B) \leq P(A \cup B)$
- $P(AB) \leq P(A \cup B)$
- $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A \cup B)$

I don't have space in the design for the third one, so I'm wondering if the first two are equivalent. I've rarely seen people writing P(AB) so I wasn't sure if it's incorrect, or more niche to e.g. computer fields evaluating boolean statements.

Thanks!

Comment: Different authors use different notations.  Although I am an advocate of the last as I feel it requires the least explanation, I concede that not everyone uses it nor do they *need* to.  That said, yes... I have seen each of these over the years to represent the joint probability of multiple events.

Comment: I would personally advise against $P(AB)$ even if it is occasionally used, as it can be misinterpreted in the case of random variables as the product of said random variables, or misinterpreted as an event whose name we decided should be represented using multiple characters.  It is perfectly reasonable to see someone write $\Pr(\text{Rain})$ and not assume they mean the joint probability of the events $R,a,i$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can somehow convey that you're using Boolean arithmetic, then you could say $P(AB) \leq P(A+B)$. It still feels weird to me but it is at least consistent (if we think of $P(A)$ as $P(A=\text{True})$). I don't like option 2 as you stated it because it seems to be mixing notations.

Option 1 also seems a bit weird to me and confused me for a bit because seeing $A,B$ made me think they were random variables. But it might be reasonable to expect people to interpret it correctly in context.

Comment: Hm, it seems most people see this and think “set theory” but isn’t that also the notation for statistics? I mean if A and B are r.v.s

Comment: @AlexG I don't think I get what you mean. If they were random variables I don't know what Pr[A] would mean and especially what Pr[A,B] would mean. It makes sense that what's in the probability expression is an event, which is a set. Could you elaborate a bit more on the notation in statistics? I admit I haven't done any specifically statistics-oriented courses.